# Регулярка - удалить символы, дефис заменить на пробел

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Требуется написать следующую логику:

Удалить из строки все символы, кроме букв латинских/кириллицы и "," (запятой), а знак "-", если он встречается, нужно заменить на пробел, при этом, если между совами уже есть пробел, то его так же необходимо сохранить.

Получилось выполнить первые два условия, а найти и заменить "-" никак не получается..

```
/[^ a-zа-яё,-]/ui
```

Буду очень благодарен за помощь

Comment: Вообще-то заменить один символ на другой можно с помощью str_replace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Составьте два шаблона - первый находит несоответствия и вырезает лишнее, второй - добавляет пробелы:

```
$str = 'слово-(полслова) слово';

echo preg_replace(['~[^\pL\s,-]+~us', '~-~'], ['', ' '], $str);
```

Comment: спасибо за отклик. Но пока немного не то получилось. "-" находит и удаляет, но пробелами не заменяет.. слова слипаются..

Comment: спасибо, понял свой недочет в вопросе, подправил

Comment: извините, но пробел между словами после удаления "-" все равно не появляется. (Пробел, если был изначально, остается. C этим получилось.)

Comment: @Эдуард а попробуйте такой пример "слово-полслова", увидите, что пробел не остается)

Comment: @Эдуард теперь работает как хотелось. Класс! Спасибо большое!)

Comment: @coder675 ваш вариант, кажется, тоже работал как нужно. Спасибо за отклик! (к сожалению удалили комментарий)